# release Assembly.LoadFrom file handle

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm trying to get assembly version of an exe in C# with the following code

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(address);
return asm.GetName().Version;
```

it works perfect but if I try to delete the exe after I used this function, it says "Access Denied" since the exe is being used by another process!

is there any Dispose call or something which releases the file handle or any other solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unload an assembly from the primary AppDomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was dealt with here

[How to unload an assembly from the primary appdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain/1958566#1958566)

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to unload an assembly other than unloading the application domain.  See [How to: Load and Unload Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101(VS.80).aspx):

> There is no way to unload an
>   individual assembly without unloading
>   all of the application domains that
>   contain it. Use the Unload method from
>   AppDomain to unload the application
>   domains. For more information, see
>   Unloading an Application Domain.

If you just want to get the version of a file, try using [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx).