# C# Load different versions of assembly to the same project

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, version, .net-assembly

I'm creating some tool what performs several operations like NUnit. 
Inside this tool I open .dll assembly and invoke methods form it to run some test.

Everything is going OK till the time I need to reload .dll withour program restart. The idea is that when tool is run we copy required assembly to some temporary folder and invoke from there. If I need to reload I copy another one to another temporary folder and try to load newly copied  from another folder and load to previous assembly object

```
  ExecutingAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyFullPath);
```

But my problem is that after I change AssemblyFullPath to new one and call Assembly.LoadFrom it returns just old assembly what was loaded first time but not the second one!
Maybe the problem is that we cannot load several assemblies with different versions? What is the solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258160/unloading-the-assembly-loaded-with-assembly-loadfrom

Comment: `Assembly.LoadFrom` doesn't even try to load the same assembly twice. `Assembly.LoadFile` is a bit different and might work somehow, but be prepared to encounter a lot of strange issues even if it does. It's usually better to just do this kind of stuff in a separate `AppDomain` and reload it as needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CLR does support loading multiple versions of strongly named assemblies into the same `AppDomain`.  This only works though if your assemblies are strongly named and each one has a different version than the other.

I'm guessing it's more likely that you are dealing with unsigned assemblies.  If that is the case then what you're asking for isn't really possible.  Once a given assembly is loaded into an `AppDomain` it will remain there until the `AppDomain` is unloaded.  To get this to work you will have to abstract out all of the work around the loaded assemblies into a separate `AppDomain` and use a new `AppDomain` for every assembly

Answer (score 1):

To expand on JaredPar's answer, you will need to create a new `AppDomain` and use `Remoting` to communicate between the two.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.85).aspx to help get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
string dllFile = "C:\\sample.dll";
Assembly asmLoader = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);
Type[] types = asmLoader.GetTypes();
```

Since all resources from the assembly cannot be reloaded/replaced it's assembly resources while application is still running. It will only be replaced/removed when application is unloaded or the that Assembly that holds it.

Use LoadFile() method. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for most of the use cases since it requires the least amount of code rewriting based on the question.