# Azure shareclient works in one project and throws exception in another

Tags: vb.net, azure, visual-studio, azure-storage-files

I have a vb.net solution with a separate project containing a file class to access Azure files and 2 projects. In both I call the file class which contains this code

```
Dim mascThis as ShareClient
... mascThis is initialized ...
If mascThis.Exists.Value then ... do something ..
```

In one project this works, in the other I get the message

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I've seen this problem discussed before (assembly issues), but all projects are in the same solution in to which I added *Azure.Storage.Files.Shares 12.8.0* via *Nuget* and only the "File class" project has a reference to it, the other projects don't.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any of the below is your case.

Sometimes, we will have the situation where different parts(projects) of our solution depend on different versions of the same DLL i.e; assemblies with the same assembly name.

The error

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
> match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

suggests , your project is looking for assembly version 4.0.4.1

**Work arounds**

i.  Usually Nuget Package 4.5.3 contains assembly version  4.0.4.1.
Please check if both the projects in your solution can be worked on that assembly version and add that particular version as new version(ex:4.0.4.1) through [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the project where you are getting error. And keep the old version in place of old version.

Also Right click on the package reference and set 'specific version' to false under its properties

Example:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
```

In this example ,this way of adding specifies that the runtime should use version 4.0.6.0 in the Assembly versions between olderversion range 0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0

Else If above is not the case, the solution might need  different versions.

ii.

1. Right click in the project properties and choose the ApplicationConfiguration file and App.config
2. Add the following settings in the app.config file.

To configure multiple assemblies with the same name through [codeBases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/15hyw9x3(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#multiple-assemblies-with-the-same-name).

*Sample  code for some package say “A”* :

```
<configuration>
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="A " publicKeyToken="3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
        <codeBase version="3.0" href="...\A.dll"/>
        <codeBase version="5.0" href="...\A.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

iii.    See if you could solve that problem by using [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias).

iv. Binding redirects are added if your app or its components reference more than one version of the same assembly .See [Enable or disable autogenerated binding redirects | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection#enable-automatic-binding-redirects-manually) .If you do it manually ,you need to disable under project properties.
Manually  you can add `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` in csproj file in property group.
Ex:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**References** that can be helpful.

- [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644282/unable-to-consolidate-nuget-package-transitive-dependency-versions-in-two-net-st/59720475#59720475)
- [Referencing Multiple Versions](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application)
- [load same assembly of different version-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617794/how-to-load-same-assembly-of-different-version-in-one-application?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the overview of possibilities, this helped in approaching the problem systematically.

Comment: Thanks for the overview of possibilities, this helped in approaching the problem systematically. "Binding redirection" didn't work (even when I unchecked  "Auto-generate binding redirects" for the project. Can this be because of indirect references or some form of "hard" coding of a reference in one of the dll's? Using "codebase" with a locally made copy of version 4.0.4.1 worked when I ran within Visual Studio, but not after I created a .msi where I did add the local copy as an "assembly" to the file and included the app.config file. What could be the reason for that?