# Assembly reflection

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

i want to load all *.dll files from a directory, and to compare the date of each *.dll file with `Datetime.Now`

i use for this the Assembly factory :

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);

            try
            {  
                var myTypes = assembly.GetTypes();

                foreach (var myType in myTypes)
                {.....}
            }
```

the problem is when i want to replace the current *.dll file with the new *.dll file, i get the error : the *.dll file is used by an other process (My assembly)

so i want to run my assembler on an other domain, and when i cancel this domain my *.dll file will be free.

thx for your help.

Comment: Do you want to detect changes at runtime?

Comment: sorry i don't understand, but i want to fetch all Dll files in my directory and i show the  types of each Dll files in a ListView, and with a click i want to replace the current dll file with a new dll file, but the probleme is that the dll file is used by a Assembly, so i have to kill the assembly before i have a hand on my file

Comment: @KernelMed ofcourse its used, you are using it by loading it.

Comment: so what is the solution to decharge it ?

Comment: You can't replace dll from program whitch use this dll.

Comment: Yes. What's more, you cannot unload assembly from domain that is once loaded. But you can create domain, load these assemblies into newly created one and then unload whole domain after all operations are done.

Comment: yes this is what i want to do, but i dont know how ? how to create new domaine, how to run a assembly in this new domaine ?!!

Comment: Please, reffer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6259172/2160375 When you will stuck with sth, please ask new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need do your check at `AssemblyResolve` event.
example:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += FindAssembly;
    ...
}
```

and the event:

```
static Assembly FindAssembly (object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    //here load assembly and decide which version you want
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
    return assembly;
}
```

Comment: i need to attach my assemby to new domaine, and i don't know how to do this