# is it possible to unload an Assembly loaded dynamically in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

in .net framework was possible to load an assembly in separate AppDomain then unload it.
in .net core AppDomain not available and replaced by AssemblyLoadContext.
i can load assembly to AssemblyLoadContext as below:

```
 var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(stream);
```

there is any way to unload it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258160/unloading-the-assembly-loaded-with-assembly-loadfrom

Comment: From what I understand .NET core does not have app domains. I don't know if this can done without app domains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out this link [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14724)

**The unload api is not yet completed.**

```
namespace System.Runtime.Loader
{
    public class AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        // Allow to create an unloadable ALC. The default constructor
        // will call this method with false
        protected AssemblyLoadContext(bool unloadable);

        // Returns true if this ALC is collectible
        public bool Unloadable {get; }

        // Allows to explicitly unload an ALC. Once this method is called,
        // any call to LoadFromXXX method will throw an exception
        public void Unload();
    }
}
```

there's an open issue for the unload api and the api has been approved probably released in the future version as the milestone is under Future tag.

Comment: Supported from .NET Core 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability