# Unload assemblies

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to create a script that will output a list of Fully Qualified Names for DLLs. The script I currently have works fine when it comes to outputting the data I want.

The problem is that this locks the file. So if I want to delete one of the files that I loaded in my session I get the following message:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open in Windows PowerShell.

What do I change to have PowerShell release the lock on the file?

I usually run PowerShell script from the internal console in Visual Studio Code, but the problem also exists when I run it directly from PowerShell.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $env:computername
Get-ChildItem -Path $input -Filter '*.dll' | ForEach-Object {
    $assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($_.FullName)
    Write-Host $assembly.FullName
}
Exit-PSSession
```

Comment: [You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258160/unloading-the-assembly-loaded-with-assembly-loadfrom)

Comment: I guess you could copy the dll and then load the copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in-memory assembly:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $input -Filter '*.dll' | ForEach-Object {
    $assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_.FullName))
    Write-Host $assembly.FullName
}
```

Comment: Be sure to not load the same assembly twice, otherwise some weird situations can occur. It is a very good idea to check `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` first before performing a load.