# An analog of Assembly.LoadFrom for AssemblyLoadContext

Tags: c#, dll, system.reflection, xunit.net, dynamic-loading

I use the Assembly.LoadFrom(dll) method to load the assembly with tests and get a list of tests in the project from it

```cs
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    Assembly.LoadFrom(_pathToTestsDll);
    
    var controller = new XunitFrontController(AppDomainSupport.Denied, _pathToTestsDll);
    using var visitor = new TestDiscoverySink();
    controller.Find(false, visitor, TestFrameworkOptions.ForDiscovery());
    visitor.Finished.WaitOne();
    var tests = visitor.TestCases.Select(testCase => testCase.DisplayName).ToList(); 
    visitor.Finished.Dispose();
    return tests.GetEnumerator();
}
```

The problem is that after `LoadFrom` assembly file is blocked and I can't run it or delete it

Adding `shadowCopy: true` to the `XunitFrontController` constructor did not help

I have seen such a solution, but it is obsolete [Unloading the Assembly loaded with Assembly.LoadFrom()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258160/unloading-the-assembly-loaded-with-assembly-loadfrom)

I looked for an analogue for new versions and if I understood correctly, then this is `AssemblyLoadContext`
The problem is that it doesn't have a `LoadFrom` method that loads the assembly along with the dependencies (or I didn't find it)

How can it be replaced?

Comment: Is the DLL blocked by the OS?  Can you unblock the file from File Explorer/Properties?

Comment: @Neil I started the program and put breakpoint in it and tried to delete the dll file from the explorer, but I got an error that the file was blocked by the program process

Comment: This lock is fundamental to the way the CLR loads assemblies from disk.  Unloading is no longer an option since support for AppDomains was removed.  The only alternative is not loading from disk, with Assembly.Load(byte[]), as noted in the second answer in the linked Q+A.