# c# Closing an Assembly instance

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

When I use the Assembly.LoadFile method, I have no outside access to the file that was loaded into assembly until my program is closed. A StreamReader, on the other hand, allows me to close the stream when I am finished using it using the `StreamReader.Close()` method.

Is there some way I can do the same thing when using Assembly.Load?

Thank you,

Evan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's by design.

If you want to 'UnLoad' an assembly you have to load it into a separate AppDomain.

If you just want to release the file you could load it into `byte[]` first and use the (deprecated) `Assembly.Load(byte[] rawAssemly)` method.

Answer (score 3):

Load the assembly into a new application domain using `AppDomain.CreateDomain()` and use it with a new instance of the `AppDomainSetup` class with its shadow copying property set to true. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx

This will copy assemblies to be loaded into a directory, and it will load the copies instead, leaving the originals unlocked. Use `AppDomain.Unload(domain)` if you want to clean up when you're finished with the assembly.

Alternatively you can use `Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("path"))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the assembly into a separate AppDomain and then unload the AppDomain - that's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the DLL file into a `byte[]` (call `File.ReadAllBytes`), then call `Assembly.Load` with the byte array.

The assembly will not be unloaded, but you'll be able to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.
See this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain) in stackoverflow.
See this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2004/05/31/145105.aspx).

For @BrokenGlass' solution see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).