# ASP.NET MVC 4 automatic loading plugins dll without rebuild

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, plugins

I have question about this plugin system: [.NET 4.0 ASP.NET MVC 3 plug-in architecture with embedded views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/358360/NET-4-0-ASP-NET-MVC-3-plug-in-architecture-with-e)

It is possible when I start ptoject (web site local in visual studio using ctrl + f5) that when I delete plugin.dll from plugin folder. System automaticly detect it and disable module or when I will put new plugin .dll to plugin folder, system automaticly detect new plugin without rebuild completly solution ? I just need the plugin system which t will not need restart server when user is installing it to the aplication.

Thnaks for your help and sorry for my english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the plugins architecture : once you've loaded an assembly in an AppDomain, it cannot be unloaded ( see [How to unload an assembly from the primary AppDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain) ).

You may want to have a look at MEF : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, so this way of plugins architecture is not good ?  I saw a lot of tutorials but i still can´t find good solution. Do you know some best architecture whitch use MEF plugin plug and play?

Comment: It is a good architecture, you just have to know some of it's drawbacks.

Comment: I found plugin architecture using mef http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=159 but witout rebulding aplication, framework not detect new plugin.