# ASP.Net MVC: How to dynamically load assemblies (controllers) without an AppPool restart/recycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, module, .net-assembly, application-pool

I'm trying to write a module/plugin system for a website I'm working on.  The overall goals are:

1. That the main website does not have to be recompiled every time a new plugin is added.
2. To be able to dump DLL's and CSHTML files into a set of folders that would basically add a set of routes, controller(s), and any other assemblies that the module depends on (Entity Framework, etc).
3. To avoid marking plugin files as "embedded resources" -- especially views.
4. To be able to add and remove these modules/plugins WITHOUT having to restart/recycle the IIS app pool or unload the app domain.

I got #1-3 working by following the example of Umbraco.  Basically, I marked a method with the `PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute, and in it I shadow copy DLLs around, and use a custom ViewEngine to locate the module's CSHTML files.  When my website first starts up, my module's controllers and views are working, and assemblies are loaded:  Hooray!

However, when it came time to try part #4, I am getting this error when calling `BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly()`:

> This method can only be called during the application's pre-start 
>   initialization phase. Use PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute to 
>   declare a method that will be invoked in that phase

It's been a very frustrating process so far, and my gut tells me that this error signifies a dead end.  Is this the case, or is there a clever workaround?

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"To be able to add and remove these modules/plugins WITHOUT having to restart/recycle the IIS app pool or unload the app domain."*

It turns out that this you cannot unload an assembly from an app domain.

[How to unload an assembly from the primary AppDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Editing the `web.config` file when you add the new modules should cause the site to recompile.

You could automate this in a script, forcing your new .dll's to be copied to the live ASP.NET temp files directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check out portable areas. Essentially a regular MVC area (including views, controllers, etc.) gets compiled into a single dll. These dll's (one for each area) can be dropped into a hosting MVC website and can be called like any other MVC area.

Some references to get started:

[Portable Areas three years later – Part 5](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/11/26/portable-areas-3-years-later/)

[MvcContrib Portable Areas](http://portableareas.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I read the article you sent, and unfortunately one of the steps is to add a reference to the main project and recompile.  Deployment would cause an app pool restart.  This is one thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to this ?