# Assembly.Load(byte[]) load only once

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

This might look like a duplicate but it isn't, its actually a different question!

The scenario is this: I have a web app that iterates through all the dlls dynamically loaded into the system to access a method from it and get data. These dlls are added by users from the website.

Pseudo code would be something like this:

```
pulic void GetNews(){
    foreach(var i in ListOfDllPaths){
        Assembly dll = Assembly.Load( File.ReadAllBytes(i));
        SomeInterface if = CreateInstance(dll); //This methods does all the validation and such
        if.DoMethod();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that on each call to GetNews() the same dlls are loaded all over again, having the same dlls loaded multiple times.
I could use Assembly.LoadFrom or LoadFile, to avoid this problem, but then i would lock the file which i don't want to, because i want to be able to delete it.

Another option would be to use a new app domain to load them, call the method and unload them, but then i would also have to load the interface dll in that domain which i really don't know the path to it in the web app. Not to mention moving data from one app domain to the other is a pain and too hard to accomplish.

One third option would be to use a shadow copy, but then i wouldn't be able to delete the shadow copy same results.

Options? Basically what i need is, load the dll, use it, unload it, move on.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem here but if you want to ensure you just load a dll once couldn't you just keep a list of the filenames of the ones you've already loaded and check that list each time to ensure you only load new ones?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you need to unload it using a separate appdomain is your only option.

Comment: The problem with keeping a list of already loaded dlls would be concurrency, considering this is a web app, how would this work? Htpp requests would be serialized because of this, wouldnt it? Only 1 request per time, since i would have to lock the list, add the element, release it, or add some kind of reader-writer mechanism.

Comment: If adding `lock` to code accessing list of items is a problem for you I'd strongly recommend to use some existing implementation of plug-in system. Loading multiple assemblies with same identity in the same AppDomain will cause a lot of interesting issues as soon as you move away from very basic on-line functions...

Comment: Solved using some kind of the answer suggestion and a concurrent dictionary from C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to really unload it you have no choice but to use a seperate app domain (see [How to unload an assembly from the primary AppDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain) for example)

If you need only load each assembly once, but don't care about unloading old ones you need to manage keeping track of which assemblies are loaded yourself.  Any easy way to do this would be to take a hash of each file before you load it.  Something Like:

```
Dictonary<string,bool> loadedAssemblies = new Dictonary<string,bool>();

using(SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(byteArray));
    if(loadedAssemblies.ContainsKey(hash)) continue;
    loadedAssemblies[hash] = true;
    Assembly dll = Assembly.Load( File.ReadAllBytes(i));
    SomeInterface if = CreateInstance(dll); //This methods does all the validation and such
    if.DoMethod();
}
```

If you want to version items another approach would be to add some metadata to your interface.

Comment: If the dll is already loaded (i find it in the hash) how would i obtain the assembly back from it? Should i store the assembly reference instead?